# Mostrar la fecha correctamente en datepicker de Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, bootstrap, php7, bootstrap-4

Estoy aprendiendo a usar php y bootstrap pero estoy trabado con esto. Grabo correctamente un registro en mi base MySql , en mi form uso un datepicker de bootstrap configurado muy básicamente :

```
$('#task-form .input-group.date').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true });
```

Para guardar el registro convierto la fecha al formato Y/m/d (lo hace correctamente) :

```
  $newDate =  date('Y/m/d', strtotime($task_fecha));
  $query = "INSERT into tareas(name, description,fecha_carga) VALUES ('$task_name', '$task_description', '$newDate')";
```

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

Mi problema es cuando quiero editar el registro, traigo los valores y en el input del datepicker lo vuelca como está en la base ejemplo :  2021-03-11
Necesito se muestre con el formato que configuré el datepicker : 11/03/2021
Intenté lo que está a mi alcance pero estoy trabado ... con el siguiente codigo recupero esos datos y los muestro, quise hacer una conversión que se ve comentada en el codigo pero no funciona. Podrian explicarme como debería solucionarlo ?

```
  $(document).on('click', '.task-item', function() {
let element = $(this)[0].parentElement.parentElement;
let id = $(element).attr('taskId');
// console.log(id)
 $.post('task-single.php', {id}, function (response) {
 const task = JSON.parse(response);
  $('#name').val(task.name);
  $('#description').val(task.description);
  $('#taskId').val(task.id);
  $('#fechita').val(task.fecha_carga);

  /* $originalDate = $('#fechita').val(task.fecha_carga);
  $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
  $('#fechita').val('$newDate'); */
  
  edit = true; 
})
});
```

Comment: Algo que olvidé mencionar . Si guardo una fecha de Noviembre , o sea actual, funciona correcto. Si en el datepicker navego y selecciono cualquier dia de Octubre .. lo guarda asi : 1970-01-01  . Algo estoy errando

Comment: Si en la base de datos el campo es del tipo `date`, el formato correcto para guardarlo es `YYYY-MM-DD` (guiones en vez de barras). Si no es `date`, te recomendaría que lo cambies, es lo más lógico al ser una fecha y podría servirte después. Luego, lo más fácil es cambiar el formato de `YYYY-MM-DD` a `DD/MM/YYYY` en `PHP` antes de llegar al JS, y que el JS simplemente lo muestre.

Comment: Hola, quizás algo se mezcló xq quise dar todos los detalles. Cuando selecciono una fecha del datepicker de bootstrap y clickeo en ella, en el input del control me muestra la fecha correcta , ya que el datepicker lo configuré para que muestre dd/m/yyyy . Cuando la guardo  : $newDate =  date('Y/m/d', strtotime($task_fecha));   Guardo la variable $newDate correctamente. El problema es que si llamo a ese registro ... para editarlo .... me lo muestra en le input del datepicker con el formato YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: no entiendo porque lo hace, pero no logré que me formatee la fecha y la muestre dd/mm/yyyy  exactamente como cuando la selecciono. Calculo es no conocer bien el datepicker ... intente usar lo que está comentado al final de mi código .. pero no funcionó.

Comment: Cuando doy de alta un registro, selecciono una fecha del datepicker, y el control la muestra dd/mm/yyyy , aunque está guardada YYYY-MM-DD , o sea como debería. Cuando recupero ese registro para edicion , en el input del datepicker me muestra la fecha YYYY-MM-DD ... ya no la formatea ....

Comment: Y si , el campo es del tipo DATE